# Bootstrap attribute in Spring JSP Form

Tags: spring, jsp, twitter-bootstrap-3, jstl

I have run across a odd attribute and i'm not sure how to get working correctly. It is supposed to allow multiple selects.

Bootstrap gives this example

```
<div class="formRow">
                        <label>Multiple select:</label>
                        <div class="formRight">
                         <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple class="chzn-select width-100 form-control" tabindex="8">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option>American Black Bear</option>
                            <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
                            <option>Brown Bear</option>
                            <option>Giant Panda</option>
                            <option>Sloth Bear</option>
                            <option disabled>Sun Bear</option>
                            <option>Polar Bear</option>
                            <option disabled>Spectacled Bear</option>
                          </select>

                        </div>
                     </div>
```

You can see the multiple select in action here http://nightskyadmin.com/demo-bs3/template/forms.html

You can see that the select has a `multiple` attribute.  JSP doesn't accept this so I figured I would use `multiple="true"` however that doesn't give the same layout that bootstrap offers.

My code looks like this

```
<div class="formRow">
                <label>Devices:</label>
                <div class="formRight">
                    <form:select path="deviceId" data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" multiple="true" class="chzn-select width-100 form-control" tabindex="8">

                        <form:option value="">-- Choose Device --</form:option>
                        <c:forEach var="device" items="${devices}" varStatus="index">
                            <form:option value="${device.id}">${device.name}</form:option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </form:select>
                    <form:errors path="deviceId" cssClass="help-inline alert-error" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is there a way to get this attribute added in.  It looks like the `multiple` attribute allow s bootstrap to add a div and some other info.

Any ideas?

Comment: `multiple` is just an attribute of the `select` tag that is nothing Bootstrap specific. Judging from the behavior there is probably some javascript to enhance the select tag.

Comment: You are correct but it looks to trigger on multiple however multiple is a real attribute so it doesn't convert correctly.  If I use this outside of JSTL it works without issue.  Its just inside the JSTL.

Comment: I known it is an attribute for both the tag in the tag library but it has nothing to do with bootstrap. It is actual a jQuery plugin ([Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)). The rendered HTML is valid HTML so I would blame the jQuery tag (and as mentioned has nothing to do with Bootrstrap but a jQuery plugin).

Comment: You are correct sir, I was missing an application.js library.  Thank you for pointing that out!